# How do i make textVIew text all selected at once.Any working solution for API 8+

Tags: android

The code i am using is android:textIsSelectable="true", but it works on API > 11. On stack overflow i found the code for it to work on API > 8

```
import android.text.ClipboardManager;

textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    ClipboardManager cm = (ClipboardManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
    cm.setText(textView.getText());
    Toast.makeText(context, "Copied to clipboard", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
});
```

but where do i put it. These solutions will let me select which part of text i want to copy. How do i copy all text in textView at once without user selecting it all.

Comment: please describe what you are trying to do.  You interchangeably ask how to select/copy all text, but these are different things.  Do you need just the text?  Are you using the clipboard manager because you're trying to move this text to another program?

Answer (score 1):

You put this on your `Activity`'s `onCreate`. But notice that what this does is copy the entire content of the `TextView` when you click it. This will not show the little handles that allow the user to drag and release to select a portion of the text.

Comment: I want to copy entire content.Will the code above work for all API above or equal to 8.Should i remove android:textIsSelectable="true" frommy xml.

Comment: @user3422722 Yes, it will work for any API level. I'd suggest you to display a `Toast` message or something to let users know that text was just copied to the clipboard. I'd also suggest you to keep `android:textIsSelectable="true"` so that users can use the built in system on the API levels that do support it. If you want to copy ONLY the whole text, then you'll have to remove `android:textIsSelectable="true"`.